# Filling dataframe with "when" function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that looks like this

```
 df1:
 image-id  colorList
 -------------------------
 id1       [Red,Blue]  
 id2       [White,Grey]
```

Now I want to create a new Dataframe using `df1` that looks like this

```
 df2:
 image-id  isRed  isBlue  isWhite  isGrey
 ----------------------------------------
 id1       1      1       0        0
 id2       0      0       1        1
```

I am trying to use the following code and it does not work due to Type mismatch

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("image-id",$"image-id")
.withColumn("isRed", when($"colorList" contains "Red",1).otherwise(0))
```

I have tried

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("image-id",$"image-id")
.withColumn("isRed", when($"colorList" contains Seq("Red"),1).otherwise(0))
```

and I get this message

> Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(Red)

I have the option to `explode` the colorList on `df1`, but it is going to make my table too complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `array_contains` function, not `Column.contains` (the latter is only applicable to `StringType` columns and checks whether the string value contains a substring):

```
df1.withColumn("isRed", when(array_contains($"colorList", "Red"),1).otherwise(0))
```